# Product of sequences and limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n=0$. If the product sequence $\{nx_n\}$ is bounded ($\exists M>0$ such that $|nx_n|\leq M $ for all $n$) can I conclude that $\{nx_n\}$ converges?

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: What if you take $x_n = \frac 1n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_n=\frac   1 n$ for $n$ even and $x_n=\frac   2 n$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$

Answer (score 1):

In context:

But: What you can conclude is that there is a subsequence $(n_kx_{n_k})$, $k=1,2,3,...$ that converges (Bolzano Weierstrass).

Look at the examples given.